# Audio output stuck on device that is no longer connected

Tags: release-juno, audio

After using an HDMI TV for video and audio output, I disconnected my laptop and left the house.  After that my web browser and the video player could no longer output audio over the speakers, the system prefers that disconnected output device for audio.

Rebooting did not help.

What should I to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspected the pulseaudio was stuck for specific apps on the device that was no longer there (the TV) seeing that the system settings app could still output audio fine.

I installed Pulse Audio Control: `sudo apt install pavucontrol` .  And in here I could select the output per application.  Indeed the HDMI was still selected, changing it to the built in audio output fixed the issue.